# blackberry how to schedule applications

Tags: blackberry, scheduled-tasks

In the blackberry, I need the ability to start and close applications at certain times of the day. Say start at 8:00am and then close the app at 5:00pm. Is it possible to schedule applications this way in blackberry?

The functionality I am looking for would be similar to say cron in Unix or Windows scheduler.
I am not a developer. Is there an app which provides functionality similar to cron or windows scheduler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ApplicationManager's functionality to schedule the application launch:

```
ApplicationDescriptor descriptor = ApplicationDescriptor.getCurrentApplicationDescriptor();
ApplicationManager manager = ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager();

// Compute the time when it need to be scheduled
long toberuntime;
manager.scheduleApplication(descriptor ,toberuntime,true);
```

Also make note of date and timezone changes, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265388/notify-the-date-change/8270395#8270395)

Comment: I found that by doing a search in stackoverflow ; but I am not a developer. Is there an app which provides functionality similar to cron or windows scheduler ?

Comment: I did some search and couldn't find any, immediately. I can develop one for you if you can wait till this weekend. If it's fine for you, let me know more details on what are the use cases of the application. I shall definitely let you know when I am done; but no promises though!

Comment: Wow, thats really generous. What I would like is if you could guide me through the process. I have already downloaded the jde. Next question is how do I identify the application name. In other words, what does getCurrentApplicationDescriptor refrence ?

Comment: @user1074593 When you say "I am not a developer", what is the context in which we are supposed to answer your question? StackOverflow is a site for _developers_ to ask and answer questions.

Comment: When I say "I am not a developer", thats exactly what I mean. If this site is only for developers, maybe you should complain to the stie owners to prevent others from registering to the site in the first place.  

    If you read and "understand" the question, it is really not that complex ! Let me try and see if I can explain it one more time 

1. I need the ability to start and close applications at certain times of the day. Is it possible to schedule applications this way in blackberry? And no, I dont believe suggesting an application requires a person to be a developer.

Comment: 2. If such an app does not exist and writing a simple piece of code is the only option, I am willing to take that route to. If it is not possible, then say so and I will accept it. No need to be a jerk about it.

Comment: lol.. he's not being a jerk. it's the truth, this forum is for developers, only a developer will understand if he tries to explain. dont take it personal :)

Answer (score 1):

This is another example where a runnable is called to every minute.

Please note that you have to setup an alternate entry for the task and make sure it starts when the device starts. Application Manager is responsible for scheduling the job.

in this example, the device vibrates every time the background aep is called.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    // Create a new instance of the application and make the currently
    // running thread the application's event dispatch thread.
    if(args != null && args.length > 0 && "ticker".equals(args[0])){
        scheduleUpdate();

    }else{
        UIapp theApp = new UIapp ();       
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }
 }

private static void scheduleUpdate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Alert.startVibrate(2550);

    ApplicationDescriptor current = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor();

    current.setPowerOnBehavior(ApplicationDescriptor.DO_NOT_POWER_ON);

    ApplicationManager manager = ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager();

    //check if device has booted and is ready..
    if(!manager.inStartup()){
        try{
            TickerUpdateService tickerUpdater = new TickerUpdateService(endpointURL);
            tickerUpdater.start();
        }catch(Exception Ex){
            System.out.println(Ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    manager.scheduleApplication(current, System.currentTimeMillis() + 60000, true);
}
```